# Migrate a django project to new server with already exists postgresql database of anotehr django project

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql

I have 2 django apps on separate servers.

Both have completely different models

The database name of app1 is xxxx1

The database name of app2 is xxxx2

how to migrate xxxx2 to server1 without damage anything ?

Comment: If you dont have any duplicate keys a simple `pg_dump` and then `pg_restore` into the other database should work

Answer (score 2):

Migrating a Django project with a PostgreSQL database to a new server involves multiple steps. Below are the general steps you can follow to safely migrate `xxxx2` to `server1` without affecting `xxxx1`.

(This assumes that you have root or sudo access to both servers.)

## Backup Existing Databases

First, always backup the existing databases on both servers, just in case.

On both servers:

```
# For xxxx1
pg_dump xxxx1 > xxxx1_backup.sql

# For xxxx2
pg_dump xxxx2 > xxxx2_backup.sql
```

## Transfer Database from Server 2 to Server 1

1. Transfer the backup of xxxx2 from server2 to server1:

```
scp server2:/path/to/xxxx2_backup.sql /path/to/destination/on/server1/
```

2. Import the xxxx2 database into PostgreSQL on server1:

```
psql -U username -d xxxx2 < /path/to/xxxx2_backup.sql
```

## Transfer Django Project Files

Transfer the Django project files of app2 from server2 to server1:

```
# On server2
tar czf app2_project.tar.gz /path/to/app2/
# Transfer
scp server2:/path/to/app2_project.tar.gz /path/to/destination/on/server1/

# On server1
tar xzf /path/to/app2_project.tar.gz
```

## Update Configuration

1. Update the `settings.py` file for `app2` to use the `xxxx2` database.
2. Also, update any paths, environment variables, or settings that have changed due to the new server environment.
3. Update your web server (e.g., Nginx, Apache) to serve `app2`.

## Install Dependencies

On server1, navigate to the project directory for app2 and install the required Python packages:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

## Apply Migrations and Collect Static Files

No new migrations should be necessary since you've imported an existing database, but it's a good idea to check:

```
python manage.py migrate --fake
```

Collect static files:

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

## Test

Finally, test both applications to make sure that they are running as expected.

This is a simplified explanation, and the exact steps may vary based on your specific configurations and environments, but it should provide a good starting point.

---

UPDATE: Clarifying Comments

The command:

```
psql -U username -d xxxx2 < /path/to/xxxx2_backup.sql
```

Does the following:

- psql: This is the PostgreSQL command-line utility.
- -U username: This specifies the PostgreSQL user that you're using to execute this command. Replace username with the actual PostgreSQL username you're using.
- -d xxxx2: Specifies the database to which the SQL commands in the provided file should be applied. In this case, it's targeting the xxxx2 database.
- < /path/to/xxxx2_backup.sql: This is directing the SQL commands stored in the xxxx2_backup.sql file to be executed against the xxxx2 database.

### What will this command do? Will it create a new database with the same name xxxx2 and the existing data?

The command itself doesn't create a new database. It assumes the database xxxx2 already exists on the target server. The command will execute the SQL commands contained in the xxxx2_backup.sql file on the xxxx2 database. If the backup file contains data insertion commands (like those from a pg_dump), then it'll populate the database with the data from the backup.

### What will happen if the name already exists?*

If the database xxxx2 already exists, the command will apply the SQL commands in the backup file to that existing database. This can potentially overwrite existing data, modify schemas, etc. If the xxxx2 database contains important data, it can be corrupted or lost. This is why the backup step is essential before performing such operations.

For safety, before running this command, it's a good practice to ensure that the target database is either empty or doesn't contain any important data that hasn't been backed up. If you're migrating to a fresh environment, it's usually advisable to create an empty xxxx2 database first and then apply the command.

Comment: This is such a yummy answer

Comment: What will the psql -U username -d xxxx2 < /path/to/xxxx2_backup.sql do ? will it create a new database with the same name xxxx2 and the existing data? what will happen if the name already exists ?